# Delete records from table having foreign key (Derby)

Tags: netbeans, foreign-keys, derby, netbeans-platform, named-query

I have added some records to  tables  in a derby database. Some of the tables have foreign keys in them, if i try to delete a record from a table having foreign key, it doesn't allow me to delete the record saying there is a foreign key validation.  Even if i click "truncate table" it doesn't allow me to delete the data.

So my problem is how do i delete all the records from a table in derby where there are foreign keys?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the id's of the records you are trying to delete are used in other tables?
Try to delete the records that use the primary key of the record u can't delete.

When u have deleted them, u will be able to delete the record u wanted to delete.

Perhaps it will be possible to set some kind of trigger that is activated before deleting a record, and make that trigger delete the other records that use the primary key of the record u are deleting. This way u won't have to do it yourself all the time.

Hope this helps u.